# Is there a way to set one "//$NON-NLS" annotation for all Strings in one line?

Tags: java, eclipse, string-externalization

does anybody know if it is possible to set one //$NON-NLS annotation tag in java for all Strings in one line... maybe like this:

```
String[][] info = new String[][]{
     {"a1", "a2"}, {"b1", "b2"}, {"c1", "c2"}, {"d1", "d2"} //$NON-NLS-ALL$
};
```

I like to prevent this long line of code:

```
String[][] info = new String[][]{
     {"a1", "a2"}, {"b1", "b2"}, {"c1", "c2"}, {"d1", "d2"} //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$ //$NON-NLS-4$ //$NON-NLS-5$ //$NON-NLS-6$ //$NON-NLS-7$ //$NON-NLS-8$
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can make this work with the `//$NON-NLS` comments, but you can suppress the NLS warnings for the whole variable declaration:

```
@SuppressWarnings("nls")
String[][] info = new String[][] {
    {"a1", "a2"}, {"b1", "b2"}, {"c1", "c2"}, {"d1", "d2"}
};
```

Comment: Thank's for this info.

Answer (score 2):

You can instruct to ignore all by adding `//$NON-NLS-L$`

Comment: Actually it does answer the question, but that -L only works in globalyzer, not in eclipse: http://www.lingoport.com/software-internationalization-products/globalyzer/.  So the answer is technically wrong, but well intentioned. Voting back up.